# Can we use the distance to nearest prime to approximate large integers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, information-theory

Let's say we have two oracles, *NearestPrime* and *IndexOfPrime*, defined as follows:

> Given some integer *x*, *NearestPrime* yields the prime number nearest to *x* that is not greater than *x*.
>
> > Examples:
> >     \begin{aligned}
> > NearestPrime(3) &= 3 \\
> > NearestPrime(25) &= 23 \\
> > NearestPrime(28) &= 23 \\
> > NearestPrime(102) &= 101
> > \end{aligned}

> Given some prime *p*, *IndexOfPrime* yields the index of that prime in the sequence of all primes.
>
> > Examples:
> >     \begin{aligned}
> > IndexOfPrime(2) &= 1 \\
> > IndexOfPrime(5) &= 3 \\
> > IndexOfPrime(29) &= 10
> > \end{aligned}

If both the number of primes and prime gaps increase as a natural log of the integers, then couldn't we specify an integer *n* by the the following tuple:
$$
\left(IndexOfPrime(NearestPrime(n)), \\
n \bmod NearestPrime(n)\right)
$$

And, further, because both parameters are in log-space, wouldn't this be an space-efficient encoding for large integers?

Comment: Sounds reasonable I guess. Now how do I do arithmetic in this representation?

Comment: "primes... increase as a natural log of the integers"?

Comment: I'm looking at the prime-counting function – am I misinterpreting this?  What is the proper descriptor for the growth of primes as a function of the integers?

Comment: The $n$-th prime is [somewhat larger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Approximations_for_the_nth_prime_number) than $n\ln n$. Thus, $IndexOfPrime(NearestPrime(n))$ is not going to be *that* much smaller than $n$.

Comment: What do you mean by "log-space"? Isn't the usual way of writing a number $n$ in log-space?

Comment: You can think of it differently: Your method uniquely represents any integer using two integers. If you consider all the integers between $1$ and $N$, you need $N$ different pairs of integers to represent them. This is clearly impossible if both components of all the pairs need to stay below $\log N$ (even if you raise the log to any fixed power).

Comment: There are already plenty of $O(\ln n)$ size encodings for integers.  If you want to turn this into something practical you have to look at existing encodings and show how yours is better for certain applications.

Comment: @PeterKošinár I think you should answer with your correction about the n-th prime being in the realm of n ln n, so that I may accept that as an answer (since it corrects my misconception about this encoding's space efficiency).

Comment: @NovaDenizen My interest is in sacrificing time for space, a compact encoding encoding that requires the decoding party to search for the original value, but provides him with some test which confirms the original value when discovered.